# Twitter bootstrap v3 - button next to input isn't rounded

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I copied this code (from the [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons)) and modified it a bit:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email addresses">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Send
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The *right side* of the button isn't rounded as in the source. Result:
[image]

What I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have other CSS? The [code works as expected](http://www.codeply.com/go/PvXlcX8CRt)

Comment: Which browser? Live Example? Do you load another css after the bootstrapp css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@No1Lives4Ever your code is working fine. see the below code snippet...

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email addresses">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Send
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right. It was other css code who made this problem.